# Estimate of time required for prime factorization of large number

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have a fairly large number, say;

189835033350996327966693308352908423562156939364642656380963289904547041916999473205569166839486951244989974581942848345682606831735428346564404270713882388199644500525024630741557243099903335030417450811633549

How can I estimate the time required (even at theoretical level) to prime factorize number like these.

Can anybody give me an approximate time needed to prime factorize this number.

thanks in advance.

EDIT

Thanks for the feedbacks.

I was trying to prime factorize this number using division method, as a trial to implement in java using bigintegers. The programs doesnt end at all!

I couldnt find a proper url where i could fit this number. Please help me with a url if any.

As I observed O(log n) time complexity can be achieved using sieve method but could not work my head around how long it would actually take to prime factor a number like this.

Comment: @Moo: I guess you know that $15257 \dots 93909$ is not prime.

Comment: If I know the number is prime, as the title says, I can factor it very quickly.  If you are using trial division you have to try up to the square root of the largest prime factor.  If the number were prime, that would be up to $10^{93}$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its not large prime number.. its large number.. oops..

Comment: i have done the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a few more details, like what algorithms can be used. But as a rule of thumb, I'd say Wolfram Alpha can factorize any number less than $10^{200}$ in a few seconds. It might take more time to transmit the number to the Wolfram Alpha website and back than it actually takes Mathematica to carry out the computation.

Comment: I Could not find a proper url.

Comment: @randomuser Seriously? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1898350333509963279666933083529084235621569393646426563809632899045470419169994732055691668394869512449899745819428483456826068317354283465644042707138823881996445005250246307415572430999033350

Comment: Though in fairness to you, @randomuser, Wolfram Alpha does have a 200 character limit. Probably doesn't apply to Wolfram Cloud Lab, but you have to have at least a free account on that one.